# How many triangles can be made from $n$ points on a line and not on a line

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> We have a plane with $n$ points $(n\ge 34)$. $17$ points are on one line, and the rest are  positioned such that no three points are on one line. How many triangles can we make from the $n$ points?

I tried a complete counting approach because I think it would be simpler then graphs, we also haven't seen much use of graph theory in combinatorial applications.

My attempt:

Define the 17 points that are on the line as $A$ and the rest as $B$.

From the points in $B$ only: $\binom {n-17} 3$.

Two points from $A$ and one from $B$: $\binom {17} 2 \binom {n-17} 1$.

Two points from $B$ and one from $A$: $\binom {17} 1 \binom {n-17} 2$.

So the answer would be $\binom {n-17} 3 + \binom {17} 2 \binom {n-17} 1 +\binom {17} 1 \binom {n-17} 2$.

Is this alright? There's no double counting since the cases are foreign to each other right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct. Alternatively, notice that you can choose any $3$ points that are not on that particular line. That gives a total of $\binom{n}{3} - \binom{17}{3}$ possible triangles, which in fact has the same value as your answer.

Comment: How did you know that they're equivalent? Did you expand the binomial expressions?

Comment: @kuhaku: It is a simple combinatorial identity. If you want to choose $3$ items from $n$, it clearly divides into disjoint cases depending on how many you choose from the first $17$. So there is no need to actually calculate anything to verify that they have the same value.